# Sorting a recursive list of objects by string property in Java

Tags: java

I've a recursive list of objects with unknown depth and I'm trying to sort all objects within the lists by a `string` property `name`.

`exampleData.json`

```json
[
    {
        "name": "B",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Bb",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Bc",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Ba",
                "items": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "A",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Ab",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Aa",
                "items": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`sortedData.json`

```json
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Aa",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Ab",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Ac",
                "items": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Ba",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Bb",
                "items": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Below is my current approach in Java. While it seems to work for small amounts of data, I'm uncertain of how professional it is since I've no experience with recursion and its performance.

```java
    private void sortRecursivelyByName(List<Item> items) {
        if(items== null || items.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        items.sort((a,b) -> {
            this.sortRecursivelyByName(a.items);
            this.sortRecursivelyByName(b.items);
            return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly improve the performance by not doing the recursive calls in the `Comparator` implementation. When the list sorts itself, it will most likely consult this `Comparator` multiple times for the same item, so all of the nested lists will be sorted multiple times.

Instead, propagate the recursion manually.

```
private void sortRecursivelyByName(List<Item> items) {
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (Item item : items) {
        sortRecursivelyByName(item.items);
    }
    items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getName));
}
```

The performance impact of a recursive approach, if any, is dependent on the *recursion depth* and should be neglectable unless you are somewhere in the thousands. Conveniently, your recursion depth is equal to your input depth, so you might be able to tell, how likely that is going to happen.

And even then, if the lists are sufficiently large, the sorting will take most of the time, and that would not change in an iterative approach.